# Edit button grayed out for "Launch and Activation permissions" in DCOM Config -> Properties -> Security -> Customize

Tags: windows-11, crash, regedit, dcom

So my Windows 11 computer is currently randomly rebooting. Following the instructions at https://www.windowscentral.com/how-find-reason-pc-shutdown-no-reason-windows-10 I traced it back to this:

```
The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe (DESKTOP-U841MH2) has initiated the power off of computer DESKTOP-U841MH2 on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x500ff
 Shutdown Type: power off
 Comment:
```

When I remove the filter from the Event Viewer I see that that is always proceeded by a bunch of these messages:

```
The server {AB8902B4-09CA-4BB6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

So I Google'd that and found [DCOM Errors ID 10010 Thumbnail Cache Out of Proc Server and WPN SRUM COM Server](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/dcom-errors-id-10010-thumbnail-cache-out-of-proc-server-and-wpn-srum-com-server.2795/) which in turn led to https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/102665-event-id-10016-clsid-appid.html#post1271001 . Per that I changed the owners of HKEY_Classes_Root\CLSID\AB8902B4-09CA-4BB6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5 and HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\AppID\AB8902B4-09CA-4BB6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5 to Administrators but when I go to DCOM Config -> Properties -> Security -> Customize the Edit button is grayed out:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did the reboot error produce a mini dump file?

Comment: @John - where would I find that? That said, the goal of my question wasn't to find out why my laptop was randomly rebooting (if it was then I chose the title very poorly) but rather to find out why "Launch and Activation permissions" is grayed out. Thus far I'm satisfied with the explanations I've read online as for why my computer is randomly restarted.

Comment: The reason I went into as much detail as I did for _why_ I was trying to do this is because I've never in my life had an occasion to go into DCOM Config and idk why one would unless directed to do so by an online post. I mean, I suppose that would be an interesting question, as well, what the whole point of the DCOM Config is, but that's not really my main focus atm

Comment: There is a mini dump folder. Check in Windows or Windows \ System32

Comment: @John - I'm not seeing any recent minidumps at C:\Windows\Minidump . The random reboot has happened twice in the past two days but the most recent minidump is from two weeks ago. That said, what would the mini dump file tell you? If you're trying to figure out the random reboots then I'd rather create a new question focused on that vs on why the "Launch and Activation permissions" is grayed out.

Comment: If there is no Mini Dump folder then no Dump was produced. You may need to back up and rebuild the computer.